# I resetted my main branch of git repo. How to restore that branch?

Tags: git, github, branch, checkout, restore

There is a branch named "main" in my repo. It had almost 70 commits earlier. In my local system I made changes in code and made a commit. but while pushing I made this commands

```
git checkout -b main
git push -f origin main
```

So after that in my "main" branch all that 70 commits got lost and instead there is only a single latest commit So I think all that 70 commits got deleted.

I tried `git reflog` command, but in that it only showing only 1 SHA of that latest commit its not showing SHA of all 70 commits.

So now I want to restore my "main" branch to that point where it has all the 70 commits or simply I want to restore my "main" branch containing all the 70 commits

Comment: 1. in your local repository: check if `git reflog origin/main` has the previous state of your main branch. 2. where is your remote server located ? some hosting service like github ?

Answer (score 0):

I just contacted github support and they provided me with a my github repo tree link, in that link there was a branch which was lost by me so i just created new branch from source branch as that SHA from the link provided from support so hy this I was able to copy a new branch which consisted of all my previous commits. A great thanks to github support.